# Linq to Sql Enums and Conditional Operator

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, enums

Whichever way I do it, it seems something goes wrong when using the conditional operator on enum values in Linq to Sql. For example

```
var ret = from listings in db.Listings
  select new Listing
   {
   ID = listings.ID,
   //etc
   OrderStatus = listings.OrderItems.Count > 0 
   ? listings.OrderItems.First().Order.OrderStatus : OrderStatus.NotCheckedOut
};
```

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
>   Conversion failed when converting the
>   nvarchar value 'Charged' to data type
>   int..

When I leave the enum field as nvarchar mapped to a string I get similar conversion errors. How to workaround this ?

Comment: btw it works fine when theres no conditional so Converting the nvarchar to the int is not a problem ?!!

Comment: What is this "Charged" nvarchar?

Comment: That's the enum stored as a string in the Orders table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works, maybe there's a better way though ?

```
var ret = from listings in db.Listings
let ordS = listings.OrderItems.Count > 0 ? 
                        listings.OrderItems.First().Order.OrderStatus.ToString() : OrderStatus.NotCheckedOut.ToString()
  select new Listing
   {
   ID = listings.ID,
   //etc
   OrderStatus = (OrderStatus)Enum.Parse(typeof(OrderStatus), ordS)
};
```

Comment: Also don't forget to set the type of your Linq to sql entity property to be the enum type you do this in the designer and use the following syntax "global::OrderStatus"